# Getting network UNCLAIMED in Debian 8.3

Tags: debian, linux-networking, wifi, drivers, kernel-modules

When i check for `lshw` , i get following result

```
user@user# lshw -c network
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: I210 Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 03
       serial: **
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=igb driverversion=5.2.15-k firmware=3.25, 0x800005d0 ip=10.10.6.100 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:16 memory:f7e00000-f7e7ffff ioport:e000(size=32) memory:f7e80000-f7e83fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: I210 Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: eth1
       version: 03
       serial: **
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=igb driverversion=5.2.15-k duplex=full firmware=3.25, 0x800005d0 ip=192.168.2.100 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:17 memory:f7d00000-f7d7ffff ioport:d000(size=32) memory:f7d80000-f7d83fff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: AR9462 Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f7c00000-f7c7ffff memory:f7c80000-f7c8ffff
```

The driver needed are ath9k as per my research. but modprobe ath9k is giving following error.

```
user@user#modprobe ath9k
modprobe: FATAL: Module ath9k not found.
```

In Actual this files are there inside library module folder

```
user@user:/lib/modules/3.16.0-4-amd64/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath# ls
ar5523  ath10k  ath5k  ath6kl  ath9k  ath.ko  carl9170  wil6210


user@user:/lib/modules/3.16.0-4-amd64/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k# ls
ath9k_common.ko  ath9k_htc.ko  ath9k_hw.ko  ath9k.ko
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found my solution ,i had installed two kernels by mistake.
1)Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64
2)Linux 3.18.13-rt10mah+ x86_64

ath9k driver was available in 3.16.0-4 folder but not in 3.18.13's folder
Because of that modprobe ath9k didn't worked.

Copying driver files from 3.16.0.4's directory to 3.18.12-r10 also didn't worked.

So i downloaded backported ath9k driver dump from
[Backported kernal portal](https://backports.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page)
[To Download all stable releases](https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/stable/)

and selected version, near to my kernal's version : v3.18-rc1
and foloowed following steps.

1. download kernal backup
2. Extracted the backup
3. navigated to extracted folder location
4. Commanded following commands
   (use command `Make help`  to see possible options to install the drivers from package)

   sudo make defconfig-wifi
   sudo make
   sudo make install
   sudo update-initramfs -u
   reboot

And it solved my initial problem of Network remaining unclaimed.
if anyone still facing similar issue: email me on hd.gcet[AT]gmail
i'll be happy to help you, because it took 5 days for me to resolve, and documentation on installation this way is available very little, and in bits and pieces.